# Oracle decode function auto trims string with leading zeros. How to prevent that?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a procedure in Oracle DB which has a very simple task of inserting data. But when tax number is a data with leading zeros, decode function auto trims it. How to prevent that happening? For example the data that I want to insert is '0012345678' but procedure inserts '12345678'. CH_TAX_NO has a VARCHAR2(40) type.

```
 PROCEDURE PRC_DML_SAVE_DATA
    (
    P_TAX_NO                IN SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME."CH_TAX_NO"%TYPE,
    P_CITIZEN_NO            IN SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME."RF_CITIZEN_NO"%TYPE,
    P_STATUS                IN NUMBER,
    P_QT_LIMIT              IN SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME."QT_LIMIT"%TYPE
    )
    IS
    BEGIN 
            INSERT INTO SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME
                (SQ_CUSTOMER_NO,
                CH_TAX_NO,
                STATUS,
                QT_LIMIT, 
                DT_SAVE_DATE)
            VALUES
                (SCHEMA_NAME.SQ_CUSTOMER_NO.NEXTVAL,
                DECODE(P_TAX_NO, NULL, P_CITIZEN_NO ,P_TAX_NO),
                P_STATUS,
                P_QT_LIMIT, 
                SYSDATE);
    END PRC_DML_SAVE_DATA;
```

But when I try to do it as shown below, it works.

```
PROCEDURE PRC_DML_SAVE_DATA(...--parameters--...)
IS
v_ch_tax_no SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME."CH_TAX_NO"%TYPE;
BEGIN

IF P_TAX_NO IS NULL THEN
     v_ch_tax_no := P_CITIZEN_NO;
ELSE
     v_ch_tax_no := P_TAX_NO ;
END IF;

INSERT INTO SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME
                    (SQ_CUSTOMER_NO,
                    CH_TAX_NO,
                    STATUS,
                    QT_LIMIT, 
                    DT_SAVE_DATE)
                VALUES
                    (SCHEMA_NAME.SQ_CUSTOMER_NO.NEXTVAL,
                    v_ch_tax_no,
                    P_STATUS,
                    P_QT_LIMIT, 
                    SYSDATE);

END PRC_DML_SAVE_DATA;
```

Comment: Please include a test case that reproduces the issue, including `create table`, sample data etc (or link to a dbfiddle, sqlfiddle etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, it shouldn't, as far as I can tell. I can't reproduce it.

Sample table and procedure:

```
SQL> create table table_name (id number, ch_tax_no varchar2(40));

Table created.

SQL> create or replace procedure p_test
  2    (p_id         in number,
  3     p_tax_no     in varchar2,
  4     p_citizen_no in varchar2
  5    )
  6  is
  7  begin
  8    insert into table_name (id, ch_tax_no)
  9    values
 10    (p_id,
 11     decode(p_tax_no, null, p_citizen_no, p_tax_no)
 12    );
 13  end;
 14  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing all combinations of `p_tax_no` and `p_citizen_no`:

```
SQL> begin
  2    p_test (1, null   , null);
  3    p_test (2, null   , '00123');
  4    p_test (3, '00456', null);
  5    p_test (4, '00456', '00123');
  6  end;
  7  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from table_name order by id;

        ID CH_TAX_NO
---------- ----------------------------------------
         1
         2 00123
         3 00456
         4 00456

SQL>
```

All `ch_tax_no` rows contain leading zeros.

---

BTW, `decode` isn't the best choice for that purpose; use `nvl` or `coalesce`, e.g.

```
nvl (p_tax_no, p_citizen_no)

coalesce (p_tax_no, p_citizen_no)
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I also didnt understand why this happens and decode funtion trims the leading zeros. And thank you for the additional advice to use nvl / coalesce methods.